# I want to bind keys in jquery

Tags: jquery, replace, triggers, binding

I am currently solving a task for a calculator in jQuery and I have this issue:
I want to make the buttons of my calculator operable only with the keyboard: as in - if I press the digit 8 on the keyboard the number 8 will be displayed on the screen. I managed to do so with the signs(digits from 0-9, symbols (+-*/,) but I have no clue how I can trigger  the wanted action from the symbols via keyboard. How can I make the link.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {       
            var $calc = $("#calculator");
            var $display = $("#display");
            var $numbers = $("#numbers button");
            var $operators = $("#operators button");
            var $colspan = $(".colspan");

            var init = 0;
            var operand = init;
            var operation = null; 
            var afterOperation = false;

            var reset = function() {
                $display.text(init);
                operand = null;
                operation = null;
            }

            $numbers.not($('#colspan')).click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var currValue = parseFloat($display.text());
                if(afterOperation == false) {
                    if($display.text() == init && $display.text().indexOf(',')<0) {
                        $display.text($(this).text());
                    } else {
                    $display.append($(this).text());
                    } 
                } else {
                    $display.text($(this).text());
                    afterOperation = false;
                }
            });
            $(window).keypress(function(event) {
                        switch (event.key) {
                        case "1":
                                $display.append("1");
                                break;
                        case "2":
                                $display.append("2");
                                break;
                        case "3":
                                $display.append("3");
                                break;
                        case "4":
                                $display.append("4");
                                break;
                        case "5":
                                $display.append("5");
                                break;
                        case "6":
                                $display.append("6");
                                break;
                        case "7":
                                $display.append("7");
                                break;
                        case "8":
                                $display.append("8");
                                break;
                        case "9":
                                $display.append("9");
                                break;
                        case "0":
                                $display.append("0");
                                break;
                        case "+":
                                $display.append("+");
                                break;
                                                    case "-":
                                $display.append("-");
                                break;                                      
                        case "/":
                                $display.append("/");
                                break;
                        case "*":
                                $display.append("*");
                                break;          
                        case ",":
                                $display.append(",");
                                break;      
                        case $.ui.keyCode.:
  console.log( "down" );
  break;                                    
                    }
            });
            $operators.click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var currValue = $(this).text();
                var currOperand = parseFloat($display.text());
                if(currValue != 'CE') {
                if(operation != null && !afterOperation){
                    switch(operation) {
                        case '+':
                            $display.text(operand + currOperand);
                            break;
                        case '-':
                            $display.text(operand - currOperand);
                            break;
                        case '*':
                            $display.text(operand * currOperand);
                            break;
                        case '/':
                            if(currOperand != 0) {
                                $display.text(Number(operand / currOperand).toFixed(1));
                            } else {
                                alert("ERROR");
                                reset();
                            }
                            break;
                        }   
                    }
                }
                if(currValue != '=') {
                        operation = currValue;
                } else {
                        operation = null;
                        afterOperation = false;
                        return;
                }
                if(currValue != 'C') {
                   operation = currValue;
                } else {
                    $display.text(init);
                }   
                if(currValue != '←') {
                   operation = currValue;
                } else {
                   $display.text($display.text().substring(0,$display.text().length-1));
                }
                if(operand = parseFloat($display.text())) {
                        afterOperation = true;
                } else {
                    reset();
                }

            });
```

Also I would like to replace the dot sign displayed on the calculator´s screen with a comma( in my HTML code the sign for digits is a comma but on the screen it appears as a dot and when I try to add/subtract numbers with digits the comma is jumped and the results are wrong).
Help?

Comment: Why not just use an input field for that?

Comment: Doesn't have an MRE

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you aren't reading the correct codes from the input? Try:

```
$(window).keypress(function(a){
      $("#display").append((String.fromCharCode(a.which)));
})
```

Comment: What I mean is I want to bind an operation with the operation butoon : as in when I press "=" i want the final value to be returned, whenn I press "+" I want the code to know it has to make an addition